# How to unpivot table from boolean form

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a table like this where type (A, B, C) is represented as boolean form

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Two | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Three | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I want to have the table like

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| One | A |
| Two | C |
| Three | B |

Answer (score 2):

You can `melt` and select the rows with 1 with `loc` while using `pop` to remove the intermediate values:

```
out = df.melt('ID', var_name='Type').loc[lambda d: d.pop('value').eq(1)]
```

output:

```
      ID Type
0    One    A
5  Three    B
7    Two    C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
x,y = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:])
out = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df.loc[x,'ID'], 'Type': df.columns[y]})
```

Output:

```
      ID Type
0    One   ID
1    Two    B
2  Three    A
```

Comment: You probably need to set ID as index and convert the df to booleans for it to work, no?

Comment: @mozway Yes, I thought `ID` was the index. And no, we don't need to convert to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the new [`pd.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies) constructor here as well. This was added in `pandas` version 1.5

Note that this also preserves the original order of your ID column.

```py
df['Type'] = pd.from_dummies(df.loc[:, 'A':'C'])

print(df)
      ID  A  B  C Type
0    One  1  0  0    A
1    Two  0  0  1    C
2  Three  0  1  0    B

print(df[['ID', 'Type']])
      ID Type
0    One    A
1    Two    C
2  Three    B
```

Comment: That's a nice one, but you have to be sure that there is **exactly one** 1 per row